# Testing react native app with detox CoordinatorLayout Error

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to integrate Detox into our React Native app for testing. However, when building I am getting the error:

```
Task :react-native-navigation:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForReactNative57_5DebugAndroidTest FAILED
D8: Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior
```

I have forced the same version of support libs onto all of my dependencies. Here's my build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    // OkHttp 3.5.0+ includes the websockets API, so we need this to prevent a conflict
    // https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3040
    // exclude module: 'okhttp-ws'

    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.android.support:support-annotations:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        force "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        force "com.android.support:support-v13:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        force "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        force "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        force "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        force "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        force "com.android.support:customtabs:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
//        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-common:${rootProject.ext.gmsVersion}"
        // force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        // force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
//        force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
    implementation project(':lottie-react-native')
    implementation group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'support', version: '2.2.1'
    implementation(project(':bugsnag-react-native')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-cookies')
    implementation(project(':react-native-google-signin')) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }
    implementation(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    // RNFirebase required dependencies
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-analytics'
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-measurement-connector-impl'
    }
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-measurement-connector-impl'
    }

    // implementation(project(':react-native-camera')) {
    //     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview'
    //     exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    // }
    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')
//    implementation(project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')) {
//        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview'
//    }
    // For WebP support, including animated WebP
//    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.3.0'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[4,5)'

    implementation project(':react-native-uuid-generator')
    implementation(project(':react-native-device-info')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation(project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    implementation(project(':react-native-secure-key-store')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation(project(':react-native-navigation')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation(project(':react-native-geolocation-service')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation(project(":rncamerakit")) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.19.1' // native sdk of amplitude
    implementation project(':react-native-amplitude-analytics') // our react-native module
    androidTestImplementation(project(path: ":detox"))  {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}
```

This is in the project's build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        repositories {
           maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
        }
    }
}

ext {
    // buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3" // try 26.0.3?
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 19
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    gmsVersion = "15.0.0"
}

subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate {
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
                variantFilter { variant ->
                    def names = variant.flavors*.name
                    if (names.contains("reactNative51") || names.contains("reactNative55") || names.contains("reactNative56") || names.contains("reactNative57") || names.contains("minReactNative44")) {
                        setIgnore(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle version is set to 4.10:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

I have also run app:dependencies, but can't see where support design might be getting used with 2 versions.